# Error Connecting to Database via PHP

Tags: php, mamp

I am trying to connect to my database via PHP but get blank page when I run through Safari(http://pushchat.local:11111/test/databasename.php)

I can see my datbasename.php file under http://pushchat.local:11111/test/ as shown below:
[image]

Following is my PHP code:

```
try
{
    if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
        define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : ‘development’);

    require_once '../api_config.php';
    $config = $config[APPLICATION_ENV];

    $pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
        $config['db']['username'], 
        $config['db']['password'],
        array());

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');

    echo 'Database connection successful!';
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Could not connect to the database. Reason: ' . $e;
}
```

I even tried to put a stop sigh using codebug but I think it never stops.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to debug your code by `exit` or `die()`

Comment: what is the error? is apache  and mysql running? did you check phpinfo() ?

Comment: I see `database.php` but no `databasename.php`

Comment: Use your catch to output actual error messages `$errorMsg = $e->getMessage();  echo $errorMsg;`

Comment: Yes both MySql and Apache Servers are running and I don't see any error. the link i used is : http://pushchat.local:11111/test/database.php and i get blank page with no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Sorry But I'm Seeing database.php Not databasename.php.
Have You Even Checked If The File Exists?
Also Connecting To The Database Should Be Typed In Config  File & You should require It In You're Main PHP File.
For Example The Config File Should Look Like This:

```html
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');  //here is the host, username and password of mysql account.instead of localhost type in your websites domain name. 
if (!$connection){                                              //and instead of password,type in your own password.
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

& The Main PHP Should Look Like this:

```html
<?php
require('config.php'); //requires the config.php page
//rest of the code goes here...
?>
```

Also On Line 10,You Have Missed A Closing Single-Quote.

Comment: Notice the OP is using PDO. Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing quote -

```
'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'].'',
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Note the additional single-quote which balances the line. Error checking would have caught this.